# Playwright - expect error - how to do it?

Tags: reactjs, e2e-testing, playwright

I am writing my first e2e tests in Playwright. Before I was using Cypress.
This is a Next.js app.

I have an app that:

1. on the homepage: http://localhost:3000/ it checks if the user is
   validated (has the token in the cookies)
2. If yes, then it shows the normal pages
3. If not, it redirects the user to the /login

This is controlled in the `_app.tsx` file with Authguard:

```
const AuthGuard = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const { isLoading, isValidating, error } = useMe();

  if (isLoading || isValidating) return <Spinner belowText="Loading..." />;

  if (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401)
      return <Spinner belowText="Unauthorized" />;

    if (!error.response && error.code === "ERR_NETWORK")
      return (
        <Spinner belowText="Network error. Check if you are connected to the VPN" />
      );

    return <p>Unknown error, redirecting to login...</p>;
  }

  return <>{children}</>;
};

...

const isAuthRequired = Component.auth ?? true;
    ...
            <EmotionThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <CssBaseline />
              {isAuthRequired ? (
                <AuthGuard>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
                </AuthGuard>
              ) : (
                <Component {...pageProps} />
              )}
            </EmotionThemeProvider>
    ...
```

And this is my test:

```
import { test } from "@playwright/test";

test("unauthorized users should be redirected to /login", async ({ page }) => {
  // Go to the homepage
  await page.goto("/");

  // Wait for the Unauthorized spinner
  const spinner = await page.waitForSelector('text="Unauthorized"', { timeout: 10000 });
  
  // Verify that the spinner was found
  if (spinner) {
    // Check that the page has been redirected to /login
    const url = page.url();
    expect(url).toContain("/login");
  } else {
    throw new Error('Unauthorized spinner not found');
  }
});
```

The problem I am facing is:
When I run `npx playwright test --ui` I see that:

- `page.goto /` works fine
- `page.waitForSelector locator('text="Unauthorized"')` also works fine (the log says `locator resolved to visible <p>Unauthorized</p>`)
- however in the previous `page.waitForSelector locator('text="Unauthorized"')` if I go to the Console tab, I see `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)` which is normal, because the user is not logged in yet.

The test should not fail. Should redirect to `/login` and PASS. But the test fails because of that network error.

The hook `useMe` is the one that makes the redirect to `/login`:

```
const useMe = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return useSWR(
    "/users/me",
    (url: string) => axios.get<MeResponse>(url).then((res) => res.data),
    {
      revalidateOnFocus: false,
      onError: () => {
        router.push("/login");
      },
    }
  );
};
export { useMe };
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to wait for url to redirect and *then* verify?

Use [toHaveURL](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-pageassertions#page-assertions-to-have-url) assertion.

`await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*login/)`;

So that it will wait for url to redirect and does not verify the url immediately before the change.